# Как добавить обфуксацию кода?

Tags: java, android, proguard

Проект имеет следующие строки в build.gradle modulelvl:

```
android {
    //...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
//...
}
```

Так же имеется proguard-rules.pro :

```
#retrofit
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions

#moxy
-keep class **$$PresentersBinder
-keep class **$$State
-keep class **$$ParamsHolder
-keep class **$$ViewStateClassNameProvider
-keepnames class * extends com.arellomobile.mvp.*

# retrofit
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class com.naman14.timber.lastfmapi.models.** { *; }

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.app.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn rx.**

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*

#Support appCompat
-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

#Support design
-dontwarn android.support.design.**
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }

#Gson
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

#Parcels
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep class org.parceler.Parceler$$Parcels


#Glide
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}

#Leakcanary
-dontwarn com.squareup.haha.guava.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.haha.perflib.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.haha.trove.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.leakcanary.**
-keep class com.squareup.haha.** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.leakcanary.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.app.Notification


#Timber
-dontwarn org.jetbrains.annotations.**
```

Собираю подписанный апк релизной версии, после чего утилитой dex2jar декомпилирую из апк в jar и просматриваю содержимое пакетов. Все имена java классов остались не тронутыми, заменились только приватные методы и названия переменных классов.

До этого ковыряясь в чужик апк замечал что в них практически весь проект (за исключением некоторых android компонентов) был корректно обфусцированы в том числе имена классов. Хочется добиться похожего результата.

Что я делаю не так и как мне этого добиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге спустя некоторое время пришлось вернуться к этому вопросу. Все работало верно. Для Android стандартная обфускация (иначе - бесплатная ProGuard), которую трудно назвать полноценной обфускацией, выполняет все именно так как и задумано - изменения не касаются названий Activity, View (и некоторых других классов которые могут быть точкой входа в приложение, подробнее в proguard.default или на оффсайте) так как ProGuard не имеет доступа к изменению AndroidManifest и некоторых других ресурсов с метаинформацией. 
Требуемый мне уровень обфускации (именно такой какой я себе представлял) могут себе позволить DexGuard (с рантайм работой в т.ч.) и некоторые другие платные решения.